# Facebook iOS SDK 3.2 Graph object returned from User Request not updating

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Update: It looks like the returned graph object is not updating. I've changed the message field and verified the sender is sending out the correct message (at least it shows up in the web dialog view), but the receiver is still receiving the old message.

---

I'm running into a problem reading the data appended to a facebook request coming back to the app through deep linking. I've followed the tutorials in the facebook SDK, and can send/receive notification requests with title and message, but the data I'm appending doesn't seem to show up for the receiver. Here's my code:

Sender:

```
    FBSBJSON *jsonWriter = [FBSBJSON new];
NSDictionary *gift = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"5", @"social_karma",
                      @"1", @"badge_of_awesomeness",
                      nil];

NSString *giftStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:gift];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               giftStr, @"data",
                               nil];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_photos", nil];
appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];

[appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                 FBSessionState status,
                                                 NSError *error) {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photoID:%@", self.photoModel.photoID];

    // Display the requests dialog
    [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:appDelegate.session
     message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
     title:@"What do you think? I just rate this person an "
     parameters:params
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the send request callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Send button
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}];
```

Receiver (in app delegate):

```
- (void) notificationGet:(NSString *)requestid {

NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_photos", nil];
self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];

[self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                 FBSessionState status,
                                                 NSError *error) {
    [FBSession setActiveSession:self.session];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:requestid
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  NSString *title;
                                  NSString *message;
                                  if ([result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                                      title = [NSString
                                               stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a gift",
                                               [[result objectForKey:@"from"]
                                                objectForKey:@"name"]];
                                      FBSBJSON *jsonParser = [FBSBJSON new];
                                      NSDictionary *requestData =
                                      [jsonParser
                                       objectWithString:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
                                      message =
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Badge: %@, Karma: %@",
                                       [requestData objectForKey:@"badge_of_awesomeness"],
                                       [requestData objectForKey:@"social_karma"]];
                                  } else {
                                      title = [NSString
                                               stringWithFormat:@"%@ sent you a request",
                                               [[result objectForKey:@"from"] objectForKey:@"name"]];
                                      message = [NSString stringWithString:
                                                 [result objectForKey:@"message"]];
                                  }
                                  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                                        initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil,
                                                        nil];
                                  [alert show];
                              }
                          }];
    }];
}
```

Again, I'm able to get the message and title through, just not the data (params).

Thanks!

Comment: Update: It looks like the returned graph object is not getting updated. I just changed the message the sender sends, and verified it is being sent to facebook as it shows correctly in the sender's web dialog, but the receiver is still getting the old message. Any idea why this is?

Comment: What have you found, Jimmy?

Comment: It turns out I wasn't clearing the alerts from facebook. So the same old alert kept popping up.